# Link function1.__doc__ to function2.__doc__

Tags: python, docstring

Does anybody know if it is possible to link a `function1.__doc__` to a `function2.__doc__` without writting it 2 times ?

For example I tried something like:

```py
def function1():
    """This is my function1 doc !
    """
    pass

def function2():
    __doc__ = function1.__doc__
    pass


>>> help(function2)
>>> 'This is my function1 doc !'
```

The last line is what I would like to have.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Do you want to keep it as "my function1 doc" even in the second function?

Comment: Yes, my function1 is like the master function and the function2 is only use to call function1. So they have the same parameters and return the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just assign it at after you define the function.

```
def function1():
    """This is my function1 doc !
    """
    pass

def function2():
    pass
function2.__doc__ = function1.__doc__
```

Since a function is just an object in python with attributes, you can change the attributes to what you want.

Comment: OK great ! That works well. Thanks ! :) 
P.S. : Even if I don't write  `__doc__ = function1.__doc__` in function2.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the comment. It was a mistake of me to leave it there, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what you need to do:

```
def function1():
    pass

def function2():
    pass

function1.__doc__ = function2.__doc__ = """This is my function1 doc !"""
```

So now if you print the docstring of any function of these two, the output will be :
`This is my function1 doc !`

Comment: Don't forget to vote up to answers that are useful and accept your preferred one

Comment: Cheeky request for upvoting; but how does this answer fundamentally differ from the other answer?  If you’d like upvotes, consider improving / expanding on the content.  IMO, it’s not as effective as *neither* function has a docstring now.  User has to first ask “where’s the documentation?!” only to later find it in the unlikely location at the bottom of the module.